# Rock, Paper, Scissors Game in Java

Tags: java, game, rock-paper-scissors

I made a Rock, Paper, Scissors game and would like the code to be reviewed.

**`Main` class:**

```
public class Main {



    public static void main(String args[]){
        Game game = new Game();
        game.gameLoop();

    }

}
```

**`Game` class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

String yesOrNo;

Input inputClass = new Input();
Computer comp = new Computer();
Checking checker = new Checking();
Score score = new Score();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void gameLoop() {
        while (true) {
            inputClass.setUserInput();
            comp.setComputerInput();
            comp.displayComputerInout();
            if (checker.check(inputClass.getUserInput(),
                    comp.getComputerInput()) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Tie!");
                score.scoreBoard(0);
            } else if (checker.check(inputClass.getUserInput(),
                    comp.getComputerInput()) == 1) {
                System.out.println("Win!");
                score.scoreBoard(1);
            } else if (checker.check(inputClass.getUserInput(),
                    comp.getComputerInput()) == 2) {
                System.out.println("Lose");
                score.scoreBoard(2);
            } else if (checker.check(inputClass.getUserInput(),
                    comp.getComputerInput()) == -1) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Go to score menu? y/n");

            yesOrNo = input.nextLine();
            if(yesOrNo.equals("y")){
                score.ScoreMenu();
            }else if(yesOrNo.equals("n")){

            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid command! Continuing without going to score menu!");
            }

            System.out.println("Want to play again? y/n");
            yesOrNo = input.next();
            if(yesOrNo.equals("y")){
            }else if(yesOrNo.equals("n")){
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid command! Continuing!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`Input` Class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {

    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    private int uInput;

    public void setUserInput(){
        System.out.println("Rock: 1, Paper: 2, Scissor: 3");
        uInput = input.nextInt();
        if(uInput<1 || uInput>3){
            System.out.println("Invalid value!\nYou get Rock");
            uInput=1;
        }
    }

    public int getUserInput(){
        return uInput;
    }

}
```

**`Computer` Class:**

```
 public class Computer {

    private int computerGesture;

    public void setComputerInput(){
        computerGesture = (int) (Math.random()*4);
        if(computerGesture == 0){
            computerGesture = 1;
        }

    }

    public int getComputerInput(){
        return computerGesture;
    }

    public void displayComputerInout(){
        if(computerGesture == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Computer chooses rock");
        }else if(computerGesture == 2){
            System.out.println("Computer chooses paper");
        }else if(computerGesture == 3){
            System.out.println("Computer chooses scissor");
        }
    }

}
```

**`Checking` Class:**

```
public class Checking {

    private final int TIE = 0;
    private final int WIN = 1;
    private final int LOSE = 2;
    private final int ERROR = -1;

    public int check(int pGesture, int cGesture) {

        if (pGesture == cGesture) {
            return TIE;
        } else if (pGesture == 1 && cGesture == 2) {
            return LOSE;
        } else if (pGesture == 2 && cGesture == 1) {
            return WIN;
        } else if (pGesture == 1 && cGesture == 3) {
            return WIN;
        } else if (pGesture == 3 && cGesture == 1) {
            return LOSE;
        } else if (pGesture == 2 && cGesture == 3) {
            return LOSE;
        } else if (pGesture == 3 && cGesture == 2) {
            return WIN;
        } else {
            return ERROR;
        }
    }

}
```

**`Score` Class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Score {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    private int wins = 0;
    private int loses = 0;
    private int ties = 0;

    private String choise;

    public void scoreBoard(int winOrLoseOrTie){
        if(winOrLoseOrTie == 1){
            wins++;
        }else if(winOrLoseOrTie == 2){
            loses++;
        }else if(winOrLoseOrTie == 0){
            ties++;
        }
    }

    public void displayScore(){
        System.out.println("Wins Loses Ties\n"+wins+"    "+loses+"    "+ties);
    }

    public void resetScoreBoard(){
        wins = 0;
        loses = 0;
        ties = 0;
    }

    public void ScoreMenu(){
        System.out.println("Display Score: display");
        System.out.println("Reset Score: reset");
        System.out.println("Exit score menu: exit");

        choise = input.next();
        if(choise.equals("display")){
            displayScore();
        }else if(choise.equals("reset")){
            resetScoreBoard();
        }else if(choise.equals("exit")){

        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid command!");
            ScoreMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One little comment, the class `Random` comes with the method `nextInt()` so you could do `Random.nextInt(4)` instead of multiplying a floating point. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the numbers should be distributed more randomly than by multiplying a random floating point number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will not cover the style convention, but do know that there is work to do !

### Empty if

You should never use empty if. This would to someone thinking that the `if` is not necessary, remove it and bang your program doesn't work anymore.

> ```
>     if(choise.equals("display")){
>         displayScore();
>     }else if(choise.equals("reset")){
>         resetScoreBoard();
>     }else if(choise.equals("exit")){
>
>     }else{
>         System.out.println("Invalid command!");
>         ScoreMenu();
>     }
> ```

In this case you could add a `return`, since that is basically what you want to do.

### Enums

When you have a set of predefined values with a meaning, normally you can make a `Enum` to give them the special meaning they deserve and enhance the readability of the code.

> ```
> private final int TIE = 0;
> private final int WIN = 1;
> private final int LOSE = 2;
> private final int ERROR = -1;
> ```

This could be

```
public enum GameEnding {
    TIE , WIN , LOSE , ERROR
}
```

The name is really bad, but with an enum your method to check will be far more readable :

```
    if(winOrLoseOrTie == GameEnding.WIN){
        wins++;
    }else if(winOrLoseOrTie == GameEnding.LOSE){
        loses++;
    }else if(winOrLoseOrTie == GameEnding.TIE){
        ties++;
    }
```

Now instead of having magic numbers, you have a readable way to express the outcome of a game.

### OO structure

I didn't read for a long time your code, but I can say that you're on the good way. You've encapsulated your `Game`, `Scoring` and concept like that. You still use some magic numbers, which is an indication that there are some concept of your game that you have not abstracted in code. The `GameEnding` enum is one of those concept. It has a specific meaning in your application and will be used everywhere in your code, that should have been there, but this will come with more experience.

This is a bit advance for you (I guess), but your output should be independent of your logic code. This will help to separate your concepts , because when you'll move from the console to a GUI, all your classes will be impacted.

There is still an `Enum` missing in your code, I will leave it as an exercise to you, but some tips look at magic numbers and think of what is the base of Rock, Paper, Scissors!

Comment: If someone has a better name to propose please do so! I have no inspiration!

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I will try to fix all of the things you mentioned. Do you think i have got the OO thinking or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: @Svante I've edited what I think of your OO structure!

Comment: @Svante To add my two cents, your OO structure had me smiling a little bit because of the "sticking to what I learned" feel it had! But it's great! ^^

Comment: @Svante Ping me on this answer when you will find the missing enums in your code ;).

Comment: `In this case you could add a return, since that is basically what you want to do.` I'd rather drop the empty if altogether and change the else block to: `else if(!choise.equals("exit"))`

Comment: @Cruncher Which is a good option, but it's not expressing the same thing anymore. If you need to add a thing to do before the exit, well you will need to re-add the clause. In his case, this is not true that he need something like I just mentioned, but is something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Since Marc-Andre has covered empty ifs, enums, and OO structure very thoroughly, I'll add a bit about style.

> ```
> public class Game {
>
> String yesOrNo;
>
> Input inputClass = new Input();
> Computer comp = new Computer();
> Checking checker = new Checking();
> Score score = new Score();
> Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>     public void gameLoop() {
> ```

Since the rest of your indents seem good, I'm going to assume this is just down to Stack Exchange's kinda weird Markdown. However, since it seems like none of these are used outside of `gameLoop`, they should all be variables of `gameLoop`, not of `Game`. It doesn't matter too much in this case because `Game` only has one method, but in general we like to only give variables the scope they need (if you haven't come across variable scope, you can just ignore this until you do). Some of these names are strong (`input` is pretty standard, and `score` makes a lot of sense). Others could do with some work. `yesOrNo`, in particular, is used in two semantically different contexts: it is used both as "does the user want to see the score menu?" and as "does the user want to play again?". Separate these out into two variables, and suddenly their names can be specific: `openScoreMenu` and `playAgain`.

On spacing, I suggest adding more, or at the very least being consistent. People have different styles, and it doesn't make sense to say that others are invalid, but it is important to find a style that works well and **stick to it**. If you don't use spaces between the `if` and the `(`, then *never* use spaces between the `if` and the `(`. (Exception: when editing someone else's code, try to keep their style as much as possible.)

For example, here use use lots of whitespace:

> ```
> if (pGesture == cGesture) {
>             return TIE;
>         } else if (pGesture == 1 && cGesture == 2) {
>             return LOSE;
> ```

And here you use very little:

> ```
> if(yesOrNo.equals("y")){
>     score.ScoreMenu();
> }else if(yesOrNo.equals("n")){
> ```

Personally, I like to use lots of whitespace in my Java, but I know some people like to use very little.

Finally, in Java it's very important to pay attention to capitalization. Sure, it'd be nice if the `ScoreMenu` method was `OpenScoreMenu` instead (general rule: make method names verbs, and object names nouns), but it's much better if it's `scoreMenu`. Methods and variables are always camelCase, class names are always NormalCaps, and constants are always ALLCAPS.

(also, one irrelevant point because I'm super pedantic: choice is spelled with two c's and no s's)

Comment: About the whitespaces: Ctrl+Shift+F all the way! It standardizes the code which is always nice for version control such as Git or SVN

Comment: True, if you're using a nice IDE like Eclipse that will standardize the white spacing, and it's configurable.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of minor points:

1. Expanding on Marc-Andre `enums` suggestion, consider an array of results, so instead of

   ```
   if(winOrLoseOrTie == GameEnding.WIN){
       wins++;
   }else if(winOrLoseOrTie == GameEnding.LOSE){
       loses++;
   }else if(winOrLoseOrTie == GameEnding.TIE){
       ties++;
   }
   ```

   you'd have a single line:

   ```
   results[winOrLoseOrTie]++;
   ```
2. `Checking.check` could be significantly simplified. Notice how

   ```
   (pGesture - cGesture) % 3
   ```

   immediately determines an outcome. `1, 0, -1` mean win, tie, lose respectively.